# Transform Javascript Array into JSON FILe

Tags: javascript, json

I have this Javascript array:

```
  const myQuestions = [
    {
      question: "Question 1?",
      answers: {
        a: "A",
        b: "B",
        c: "The Correct One"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "Question 2?",
      answers: {
        a: "A",
        b: "B",
        c: "The Correct One"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    }
  ];
```

And I want to transform it into a JSON file such that I can do something like:

`myQuestions=myjsonfile.json()` ... is that possible? and if so... how?

I tried just putting all that array in between some `{}` and then making a json file out of that but that didn't work out and I don't know why

My question is:

How can I do such that I can fetch a json file from some url and then just make that variabile be the same as the json file?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(myQuestions)` ?

Comment: JSON requires to have keys and values enclosed in double quotes, otherwise it's invalid. Single quotes or no quotes at all are not allowed. Have a look at `JSON.stringify` which will do all that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` converts a javascript object into a properly-formatted JSON string.  This can be any single object or array; you do not need to wrap all the keynames in quotes or otherwise format the object in preparation for conversion to a string, it just needs to be valid javascript data (that contains no functions or circular references.)

`JSON.parse()` does the reverse, converting a JSON string into a usable object.  (The input to `parse()` *must* be a string, not something that's already an object.)

```js
const myQuestions = [
    {
      question: "Question 1?",
      answers: {
        a: "A",
        b: "B",
        c: "The Correct One"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "Question 2?",
      answers: {
        a: "A",
        b: "B",
        c: "The Correct One"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    }
  ];
  
let jsonString = JSON.stringify(myQuestions)
console.log(jsonString) // You can store that string as a .json file

let parsedObject = JSON.parse(jsonString) // convert the string back to an object
console.log(parsedObject[1].answers.c) // it's a plain JS object now
```

Lots of confusion about JSON is based in the fact that too many developers use the term interchangeably with the object it represents.  JSON is a string that can be converted into a data object; an object can be converted into a JSON string, but they are not the same thing.

So for example `JSON.parse({"this": "is an object"})` won't work because its input is already an object, it doesn't need to be parsed. Correctly, that would need to be `JSON.parse('{"this": "is a string"}')`.

Similarly, when fetching JSON via ajax, you're loading a string that needs to be `parsed()`:

```
var myQuestions; 
// error handling and response status checking skipped here for brevity
fetch('someurltoaJsonFile.json').then(response => { 
   myQuestions = JSON.parse(response.data) // convert response string to object
   // do stuff with myQuestions object here
})
// (not here, because it hasn't arrived yet)
```

Comment: Okay, that's amazing and what If I want to change the value of ```myQuestions```... so I have ```var myQuestions;``` and then a function that inside of it i change the value of myQuestions, does that appear as globally changed?

Comment: I'm talking about something like this:
```var myQuestions;
  fetch('someurltoaJsonFile.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    let jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(jsonString);

    myQuestions = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  });```

Comment: Almost.  When you load JSON you are loading a *string*; you don't need to `stringify(data)` because it is already a string.  After you've `parse`d the data it into an object, you can manipulate it as you would any other js object.  The only reason to use `stringify` is when you're about to store an object to disk as a JSON string.

Comment: Yeah but in my code, it doesn't work like this, it always tells me that ```myQuestions``` is not defined... why?

Comment: Ack, I didn't notice your extra chained `.then()`. (Sorry, it's difficult to read code in comments.)   Remove  `.then(response => response.json())`, you only need one callback here.  (I added this into the answer above.)

Answer (score 0):

Json file shoud contains valid JSON and nothing more. You can generate it by `JSON.stringify(myQuestions)`:

```
[{"question":"Question 1?","answers":{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"The Correct One"},"correctAnswer":"c"},{"question":"Question 2?","answers":{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"The Correct One"},"correctAnswer":"c"}]
```

Comment: Are the ```[]``` necessary in the json file?

Comment: Yes because in other way json will be [invalid](https://jsonlint.com/) (this array contains two objects (questions).

Comment: and why it gives me:``` JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 2 column 7 of the JSON data```

Comment: This means that json which you put to JSON.parse is invalid - in Daniel Beck [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54657123/860099) you have snippet which shows that JSON.stringify create valid json

Comment: My json is valid (and can be put to .json file) but if you want to parse it directly from string then in JSON.parse put my json into single quotes like that: `JSON.parse('[{"question":"Question 1?","answers":{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"The Correct One"},"correctAnswer":"c"},{"question":"Question 2?","answers":{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"The Correct One"},"correctAnswer":"c"}]')`